# Updating the iPhone iOS 4.0.1 to 4.0.2 SDK, Do I have to download the whole 2.5 Gigs?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-4.0.1

As the the Question asks,

I currently sport xcode 3.2.3 with iOS 4.0.1 but I want to test on my iPhone which is stuck on 4.0.2

Thus I cannot do so until the SDK for 4.0.2 is accessible from xcode.

Where can I download a patch update from 4.0.1 to 4.0.2 because the iPhone members page seems to only link me to the package including xcode 3.2.3 with iOS4.0.2 SDK

I don't want to download the whole thing because it's > 2.5 gigs and my New Zealand internet Connection is shizenhouzen.

I can't restore to a previous version, because for some reason I only have a previous back up of the iPhone on my now defunct windows PC.

Comment: Yes the SDK is the development kit for programming iPhone applications within xCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to download the entire SDK - Apple do not provide 'patches' (4.0.1 to 4.02, for example) AFAIK, and I'd be nervous about downloading anything that claims it is a patch.

It's a common grumble, twitter is a fun place when apple push these .1 SDK updates out :)

Comment: Bah humbug, that sucks, the thing is, I started downloading it last week, but it got interrupted at 2 gigs and didn't want to start where it left off. :( The plus side to it however is, that if I ever need to reinstall it, I don't have to start with a base package and work my way up...

Answer (score 0):

You do have to download the whole thing to upgrade. It really sucks. :-(

I wish I could remember to download the SDK before upgrading my devices.

You can still build adhoc releases of your app and install them using itunes if you're in a real bind - it's just the debugger, console viewing and automatic installation of builds that won't work at all.